# Toast message color Django

Tags: javascript, django, httpresponse, toast, htmx

In A django App I want to return a message from views and show it using toast.
and my main page is:

```
<div class="toast-container p-3">
  <div id="toast" class="toast align-items-center text-white bg-success border-0" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div id="toast-body" class="toast-body"></div>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white me-2 m-auto" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div id="Chamber_list">
        {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
          {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
              <div class="alert alert-danger" style="...">{{ message }}</div>
          {% else %}
          <div class="alert alert-success" style="...">{{ message }}</div>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}

        {% include 'Home/MOG_Division/rooms/Detaile/Chamber_list.html' %}
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my views.py code

```
> def edit_actl(request, pk):
    theroom = get_object_or_404(room_actual, pk=pk)
    form_erAO = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = room_actualForm(request.POST, instance=theroom)
        try:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                response_data = {'success': True,'message': 'Room updated successfully'}
                response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type='application/json',status=204)
                response['HX-Trigger'] = json.dumps({"roomListChanged": None, "showMessage": f"{theroom.room} {theroom.first_name} updated."  })
                return response
        except ValueError:
            form_erAO = 'Check your input dates'
            response_data = {'error': True, 'message': 'Room Already Occupied, Try another range'}
            response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type='application/json',status=204)
            response['HX-Trigger'] = json.dumps({"roomListChanged": None, "showMessage":'Try another range'})
            return response
    else:
        form = room_actualForm(instance=theroom)
    return render(request, 'Home/MOG_Division/rooms/Detaile/Actul_form.html', {
        'form': form,
        'theroom': theroom,
        'form_erAO' : form_erAO
    })
```

and this is my form html page:

```
<form method="post" id="yourFormId"  hx-post="{{ request.path }}" hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken":"{{ csrf_token }}"}' class="modal-content">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">{{ form.as_p }}</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>
  </div>
</form>


<script>
document.getElementById('yourFormId').addEventListener
  ('submit', function(event)
  {
      event.preventDefault();
      var form = event.target;
      var formData = new FormData(form);

        fetch(form.action, {
            method: form.method,
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log('Raw Response:', response.text());
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            handleResponse(data);
        })

        if (data.error) {
            document.getElementById('toast').classList.remove('bg-danger');
            document.getElementById('toast').classList.add('bg-danger');
        } 
        else {
            document.getElementById('toast').classList.remove('bg-success');
            document.getElementById('toast').classList.add('bg-success');
        }
        
      var toast = new bootstrap.Toast(document.getElementById('toast'));
      toast.show()
  })
</script>
```

the problem is that I need to change the color of the message when it is error.
the Javascript didn't work when I use ;

```
    if (data.error) {
    document.getElementById('toast').classList.remove('bg-danger');
    document.getElementById('toast').classList.add('bg-danger');
} 
else {
    document.getElementById('toast').classList.remove('bg-success');
    document.getElementById('toast').classList.add('bg-success');
}
```

but when

I set it without if (data.error) it gives me a toast message in red

```
    document.getElementById('toast').classList.remove('bg-danger');
    document.getElementById('toast').classList.add('bg-danger');
```

have you any solution?

Comment: Hi, did you check what exactly `data.error` has ? Also, your code will not wait for fetch call to complete instead it will always execute code from else block. Instead try moving `if (data..` and also the initialization code inside`.then(data => {` block and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Django has the messages framework built in. Just use that - it will save you a lot of headaches :)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: it is not as you think, I am already using this but in my case I must to use the above method (due to other responses from the model). So if there is a way to fix the toast to accept error and success message?

Comment: Why? You want to remove the error class, but messages provide an error type, info type etc. - all the code then goes in the view. Just submit the form and handle the logic there.

Comment: read my question please. I need to show the message as red (error), don't want to use Django message